# Where is Malkus hiding the Weystone Focus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I can't find the Weystone Focus on the body of Malkus. Where do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find [it](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Weystone_Focus), you might have to use the console to give it to you.

The ID is xx003D7D, you need to replace the xx with 01, 02 or 03, depending on your DLC setup. Press ~ on your keyboard and enter

```
player.additem xx003D7D 1
```